# Cocoa - Pasing JSON crash on null

Tags: json, cocoa, null, nsdictionary

What is the best way to prevent my app from crash?

I'm using a JSON service that sometimes get NULL fields. What is the best way to prevent it?

Right now, I've to do this on every field:

```
if(![[[[Dictionary objectForKey:@"option"] objectForKey:@"option"] objectForKey:@"option"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

The problem is that the Dic is very complex, and sometimes I even get no the field I look for. So that's a lot of validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
NSString *tel = [jsonDictionary valueForKey:@"Telephone"];   
if (tel == (NSString *)[NSNull null]) {
       // do logic here
}
```

Comment: See my edit please. I think that the solution I'm using is similar to yours.

Comment: if you have nested dictionary...you can use keyPath for readability. and then check it with (NSString *)[NSNull null]) == ur keyPath String. Also you can NSLog keypath to check if it is getting printed as null/blank or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Replace NSNull objects with nil.

This will prevent your crash from accessing "objectForKey" (doesNotRecognizeSelector).

Comment: It gives me: [__NSArrayI objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a31af0'